# Proving $m(S)=\sum_nm_n(S_n)$ is a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E_n,\Sigma_n,m_n)$ be measure spaces so that $E=\cup_n E_n$ and $E_n$ are pairwise disjoint, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\Sigma=\{S\subset E\;|\;S=\cup_n S_n,\; S_n\in\Sigma_n\;\forall n\}$. 
How to prove that $$m:\Sigma\to[0,\infty],\quad m(S)=\sum_nm_n(S_n)$$ is a measure?

I would begin by proving that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. It's easy to see that $E\in\Sigma$, but I have problem proving that $S\in\Sigma\Rightarrow S^c \in\Sigma$. Suppose that $S\in\Sigma$. Then $S\subset E$, $S=\cup_nS_n, S_n\in\Sigma_n \forall n$. That means $S^c=(\cup_nS_n)^c=\cap_nS_n^c$ and we also know that $S_n^c\in\Sigma_n$ since $\Sigma_n$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. But how does it follow that $S^c\in\Sigma$?

After proving that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra I would need to prove that $m=\sum_nm_n$ is a measure on $\Sigma$. I know how to prove that sum of measures is a measure, but only when knowing that all $m_n$ are also measures on $\Sigma$. Right now I only now that $m_n$ are measures on $\Sigma_n$. Would I first need to prove then that $m_n$ are also measures on $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much here. Just use the definitions. For checking note that each $\Sigma_n$ being a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complementation and countable union. This would give the required implication.

For the second one since $m_n$ is already a measure on $\Sigma_n$ and any $S \in \Sigma$, $S = \cup_{n}S_n$ , the properties of a measure follow.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S^{1}.S^{2},...$ be a disjoint sequence in $\Sigma$ with union $S$. Then  we can write $S^{j}=\bigcup\limits_{n=1} ^{\infty} S_{nj}$ with $S_{nj} \in \Sigma_n \forall n,j$.  Note that $S=\bigcup\limits_{j=1} ^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1} ^{\infty} S_{nj}$.  Noting that $E_n$'s are themselves disjoint we see that what is required is $\sum_j \sum_n m_n(S_{nj})=\sum_n \sum_j m_n(S_{nj})$. This is true because in a double sum  of non-negative numbers we cam always interchange the order of summation.