# Existence of Difference Measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ a measurable space and $v,\mu$ two measures such that $\mu\ge v$.

Show that there exists a measure $\lambda$ such that $\mu=v+\lambda$

Can I define $\lambda(E)=\mu(E)-\nu(E)$ where $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $\lambda(E)=\infty$ otherwise?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the only reasonable way to do it. Did you try to prove this?

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful. What if, for example, $X$ is the real line and $\mu = \nu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Your $\lambda$ will satisfy $\lambda(E) = 0$ whenever $\mu(E) < \infty$ and $\lambda(E) = \infty$ whenever $\mu(E) = \infty$. But this $\lambda$ is not a measure.

Comment: so the definition need some improvement

Answer (score 1):

First check that in general, if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are two measures on $(X,\Sigma)$ then so is their sum. In fact, a [stronger result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3357246/proving-ms-sum-nm-ns-n-is-a-measure?rq=1) is true. Then, define

$(\mu-\nu)(E)=\sup\{\mu(F)-\nu(F):F\in \Sigma, F\subseteq E,\mu(F)<\infty\}$,

and show that $\lambda:=\mu-\nu$ is a measure. It follows from this then that

$\lambda+\nu=(\mu-\nu)+\nu=\mu$.

There is a quick way to do this if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, because then the Radon-Nikodym theorem applies to produce a $0\le f\le 1$ a.e. such that $\nu(E)=\int_E fd\mu$, so if we define $\lambda(E)=\int_E(1-f)d\mu$ the result follows from elementary properties of the integral.

Comment: what about infinity case??

Comment: I know if if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite there is no problem...but the question has no restriction on $\mu$

Comment: I think the definition of the sum in my answer is general. I do not see that it places a restriction on $\mu$. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The only issue is countable additivity.  How about trying this: it should be  easy to show that $\lambda\left(\bigcup_nA_n\right)\leq\sum_m\lambda(A_n)$ and the reverse inequality will follow from an "$\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$" argument.

Comment: how can i prove that for any measurable set E the supremum  definition is actually the difference measure?? Thanks

Comment: With the definition as in my answer, if  $(A_n)$ is  a pairwise disjoint sequence, let $B\subseteq \bigcup_nA_n$, note that $(A_n\cap B)$ are pairiwise disjoint and use the countable additivity of $\nu$ and $\mu$. For the reverse inequality, start by choosing $B_n\subseteq A_n$ such that $\lambda(A_n)\leq \mu(B_n)-\nu(A_n)+\frac\varepsilon{2^n}.$

Comment: I do not understand your question, sorry! Why don't you use the hints to edit your question and show your work? It will be easier to check the details that way.